# passing php arguments to a javascript call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, nginx, url-rewriting

I hava a sort of redirect using hashs from js that goes like this:
http://example.com/#info?id=1234 
It loads the info data on a fancybox while loading the main site on the background.

Now Im trying to write a nginx rewrite so i can call to do like this:
http://example.com/info/1234 -> index.php?info=1234

Can someone point me how can i do this, using the info get on php sending the "1234" to an ajax call trying achieve the same result?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. PHP doesn't send AJAX calls, JS does (PHP is on the server). And rewrite rules don't care if the caller is AJAX, they just process the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom 404 page to parse out the last directory from the path, determine if it's a valid id and redirect. PHP can do this without any JS. I'm sure there's good reasons not to do it like this, but it should work in a pinch.